# Redirect apache when there is a % in url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I am using ISPConfig to manage my websites.

ISPConfig comes with default 404.html (and other "status" files).

I am using Apache with a PHP framework and my .htacces shows this :

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
    Options -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php?$0 [PT,L,QSA]
```

When somebody accesses a wrong url like http://example.com/i/do/not/exists, it redirects them to my custom 404 error (http://example.com/404) but with the "%" sign in the url, it displays the ISPConfig 404 error without redirecting, ignoring my .htaccess.

Comment: Which `%` char is causing 404?

Comment: `%` whatever, even alone like in `http://example.com/%`